# How to push segue between tab controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have an initial `UITabBarController` with 2 tabs (accounts, tasks).

When an account is selected the next view has different tabs (opportunities, contacts).  I am currently using a `push` `segue` which displays the original tabs and the new tabs on top of each other.

I would like to replace the original tabs with the new tabs.

I tried using a modal `segue` but then I lose the navigation functionality to return to the list of accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

In your first view controller you already have a uitabbar with two buttons (accounts, tasks)

Create a second view controller and add another uitabbar in it called (opportunities, contacts)

connect your accounts uitabbarbutton item with second view controller using "push" segue.

That's it. You don't need any replacing of uitabbar's as only one will be displayed at a time on each of the view controllers.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  The issue I would have here is this isn't using tabs.  The tabs have a user-friendly look and feel that I would like to keep if possible.  Your solution will work, but it loses the built-in functionality that tabs provide.

Comment: After re-reading your response I think my intentions were misunderstood.  In your example the accounts is a list of accounts in a UITableViewController.  Clicking an account should present the opportunities and contacts.